# Why can the width be set to 100% of the screen, but not the height?

Tags: css, layout, height

Why can I set the width of my content to 100% of the screen width, but I can't set the height of content to match the height of my screen?

The thing is, if I give my content a fixed value for the height, it may fit nicely and look good on my screen in Chrome, but not in IE, and probably not for anyone who may view the site with a high-resolution wide screen desktop or what have you.

Here's the code in a link: http://cssdesk.com/TM6Uq

**Note: The "cssdesk website has a thick "header block" on the top of their page, so that the content of my page is pushed down about 1-2ems when viewed on their site. In IE that means that you may not see the gap at the bottom between where my webpage ends and the bottom of your screen, but believe you me, it is there in my browser when viewed normally!
(I have a DELL Inspiron 1545, screen resolution is 1366 x 768=)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the below?

```
body #home{
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
html,body {
    margin: 0px;
}
html,body,#yourDiv {
    height: 100%;
}
#yourDiv {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Here is a link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q24Gz/)